# Can these two LINQ queries be used interchangeably?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

a) Would the following two queries produce the same results:

```
  var query1 = collection_1
            .SelectMany(c_1 => c_1.collection_2)
            .SelectMany(c_2 => c_2.collection_3)
            .Select(c_3 => c_3);

  var query2 = collection_1
            .SelectMany(c_1 => c_1.collection_2
            .SelectMany(c_2 => c_2.collection_3.Select(c_3 => c_3)));
```

b) I assume the two queries can't always be used interchangeably? For example, if we wanted the output elements to also contain values of `c_1` and `c_2`, then we only achieve this with `query2`, but not with `query1`:

```
  var query2 = collection_1
            .SelectMany(c_1 => c_1.collection_2
            .SelectMany(c_2 => c_2.collection_3.Select(c_3 => new { c_1, c_2, c_3 } )));
```

?

Thank you

Comment: @vossad01: I've made a typo. It's been corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippets you've given seem to be invalid. `c_3` isn't defined in the scope of the `Select` statement, so unless I've misunderstood something, this won't compile.

It seems as though you're trying to select the elements of `collection_3`, but this is done implicitly by `SelectMany`, and so the final `Select` statements in both cases are redundant. Take them out, and the two queries are equivalent.

All you need is this:

```
var query = collection_1
           .SelectMany(c_1 => c_1.collection_2)
           .SelectMany(c_2 => c_2.collection_3);
```

---

**Update:** `x => x` is the identity mapping, so `Select(x => x)` is always redundant, regardless of the context. It just means "for every element in the sequence, select the element".

The second snippet is of course different, and the `SelectMany` and `Select` statements indeed need to be nested in order to select all three elements, `c_1`, `c_2`, and `c_3`.

Like Gert, says, though, you're probably better off using *query comprehension syntax*. It's much more succinct and makes it easier to mentally parse the workings of a query.

Comment: "so the final Select statements in both cases are redundant" now that I've edited my post, would you still argue that final select in b) is redundant ( I think I agree that final select in a) is redundant )?

Comment: so queries under a) can indeed be used interchangeably when trying to select just c_3 as an output ( I do understand that Select is redundant in both queries under a) )?

Comment: Yep. Any `Select` clause that maps an element to itself is intrinsically redundant and can always be removed without consequence.

Comment: Final question if I may: since I can use both queries under a) interchangeably, is there any particular reason ( speed or code clarity or... ) for choosing one over the other?

Comment: The first is much clearer to me, but beyond that I don't think there's much difference. Query comprehensions (as Gert demonstrates) are almost always a better way of writing queries, though, unless you need to use features that they don't provide.

Comment: thank you both for your kind help - and I apologize for the typos, noone was more frustrated than I was about it :)

Answer (score 1):

a. The queries are equal because in both cases you end up with all `c_3`'s in `c_1` through `c_2`.

b. You can't get to `c_1` and `c_2` with these queries as you suggest. If you want that you need [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631.aspx) overload of `SelectMany`. This "fluent" syntax is quite clumsy though. This is typically a case where comprehensive syntax which does the same is much better:

```
from c_1 in colection_1
from c_2 in c_1.collection_2
from c_3 in c_2.collection_3
select new { c_1.x, c_2.y, c_3.z }
```

Comment: Damn it, I f**** ** again. I wrote c_3 => c_1, c_2, c_3 instead  c_3 => new { c_1, c_2, c_3 } ? Please, does your answer changes now that you know it's just been a typo

Comment: Still the same answer. `SelectMany` without result selector pushes the first collection out of scope. But I also made a typo, it's an other overload (edited it).

Comment: "b. You can't get to c_1 and c_2 with these queries as you suggest."Doesn't your query achieve the same result as query under b)? Namely, with b) query c_1 and c_2 are not out of scope even within the inner most SelectMany statement?!

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's hard for a brain without a compiler to keep track of the brackets :) Even more reason to like the query syntax.

Comment: "Even more reason to like the query syntax" I'm in the process of learning it mate, give me some time ;)