# Which query expression would be equivalent to the following LINQ query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can these two LINQ queries be used interchangeably?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017642/can-these-two-linq-queries-be-used-interchangeably)

```
var query =  from c_1 in collection_1
             select c_1.collection_2 into c_2
             select c_2.collection_3 into c_3
             select c_3;
```

is equivalent to

```
  var query = collection_1
            .Select(c_1 => c_1.collection_2)
            .Select(c_2 => c_2.collection_3)
            .Select(c_3 => c_3);
```

a) But which query expression would be equivalent to the following LINQ query:

```
var query = collection_1
            .Select(c_1 => c_1.collection_2
            .Select(c_2 => c_2.collection_3.Select(c_3 => new { c_1, c_2, c_3 } )));
```

thank you

Comment: This is very similar to a question you asked about half an hour ago...

Comment: @Magnus: How is it similar to the other question, since here I'm asking how the query can be expressed using query expression - or to put it bluntly, I have no idea how to express this query using query expression syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = from c_1 in collection_1
            select from c_2 in c_1.collection_2
                   select from c_3 in c_2.collection_3
                          select  new { c_1, c_2 c_3 };
```

Comment: I assume it is not always necessary to mark the boundaries of a subquery with parenthesis ?

Comment: @user1483278: You assume correctly, although marking boundaries might make your code more clear.  It might even never be necessary to use parenthesis on a subquery.  I can't think of any situations that require parenthesis, at least.